# How to add cookies to vue-apollo request?

Tags: django, cookies, vuejs2, apollo, vue-apollo

I use [vue-cli-plugin-apollo](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-cli-plugin-apollo) and I want to send `language` chosen by user  from frontend to backend via cookie.

As a `vue-apollo.js` I use the next template

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'
import { createApolloClient, restartWebsockets } from 'vue-cli-plugin-apollo/graphql-client'

// Install the vue plugin
Vue.use(VueApollo)

// Name of the localStorage item
const AUTH_TOKEN = 'apollo-token'

// Http endpoint
const httpEndpoint = process.env.VUE_APP_GRAPHQL_HTTP || 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'

// Files URL root
export const filesRoot = process.env.VUE_APP_FILES_ROOT || httpEndpoint.substr(0, httpEndpoint.indexOf('/graphql'))

Vue.prototype.$filesRoot = filesRoot

// Config
const defaultOptions = {
  // You can use `https` for secure connection (recommended in production)
  httpEndpoint,
  // You can use `wss` for secure connection (recommended in production)
  // Use `null` to disable subscriptions
  wsEndpoint: process.env.VUE_APP_GRAPHQL_WS || 'ws://localhost:4000/graphql',
  // LocalStorage token
  tokenName: AUTH_TOKEN,
  // Enable Automatic Query persisting with Apollo Engine
  persisting: false,
  // Use websockets for everything (no HTTP)
  // You need to pass a `wsEndpoint` for this to work
  websocketsOnly: false,
  // Is being rendered on the server?
  ssr: false,

  // Override default apollo link
  // note: don't override httpLink here, specify httpLink options in the
  // httpLinkOptions property of defaultOptions.
  // link: myLink

  // Override default cache
  // cache: myCache

  // Override the way the Authorization header is set
  // getAuth: (tokenName) => ...

  // Additional ApolloClient options
  // apollo: { ... }

  // Client local data (see apollo-link-state)
  // clientState: { resolvers: { ... }, defaults: { ... } }
}

// Call this in the Vue app file
export function createProvider (options = {}) {
  // Create apollo client
  const { apolloClient, wsClient } = createApolloClient({
    ...defaultOptions,
    ...options,
  })
  apolloClient.wsClient = wsClient

  // Create vue apollo provider
  const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
    defaultClient: apolloClient,
    defaultOptions: {
      $query: {
        // fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
      },
    },
    errorHandler (error) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('%cError', 'background: red; color: white; padding: 2px 4px; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;', error.message)
    },
  })

  return apolloProvider
}
```

taken from [here](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-cli-plugin-apollo/blob/master/generator/templates/vue-apollo/default/src/vue-apollo.js). All options are shown [here](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-cli-plugin-apollo/blob/master/graphql-client/src/index.js).

I have seen in different github discussions that `cookies` must be placed inside `headers`, for example [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/4190#issuecomment-467462129). Then I found, that `apollo-link-http` has [headers](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/http/#options) option, so at the end I tried different variations of ...:

```
httpLinkOptions: {
  headers: {

    // Tried something like:
    cookie[s]: 'language=en; path=/;'

    // and something like:
    cookie[s]: {
      language: 'en'
    }
  }
}
```

but no luck.

In case of cookie**S** I receive `Error: Network error: Failed to fetch`.

In case of `cookie`, request is sent without issues, but backend does not see `language` cookie.

I double-checked backend using `Postman` and in this case backend receives request with manually added `language` cookie.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found solution.

**FRONT END SETTINGS**

1. Create cookie:

```
export function languageCookieSet (lang) {
  document.cookie = `language=${lang}; path=/;`
}
```

2. Add `httpLinkOptions` to `defaultOptions` of `vue-apollo.js`.

```
const defaultOptions = {
  ...

  httpLinkOptions: {
    credentials: 'include'
  },

  ...
```

**BACKEND SETTINGS**

As a backend I use `Django` (currently v2.2.7).

1. For development we need to use [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers)
2. My `development.py` now looks like:

```
from .production import *

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:8080',
)
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

INSTALLED_APPS += ['corsheaders']

MIDDLEWARE.insert(0, 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware')
```

3. Add to `production.py`:

```
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = 'language'
```

The default value of `LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME` is `django_language`, so if it is suitable for you, change

```
document.cookie = `language=${lang}; path=/;`
```

to

```
document.cookie = `django_language=${lang}; path=/;`
```

4. Now in backend we can get frontend language:

```
import graphene

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

from .views import user_activation__create_email_confirmation

User = get_user_model()

class UserRegister(graphene.Mutation):
    """
    mutation {
      userRegister(email: "test@domain.com", password: "TestPass") {
        msg
      }
    }
    """

    msg = graphene.String()

    class Arguments:
        email = graphene.String(required=True)
        password = graphene.String(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, email, password):
        request = info.context

        # Here we get either language from our cookie or from
        # header's "Accept-Language" added by Browser (taken
        # from its settings)
        lang = request.LANGUAGE_CODE
        print('lang:', lang)

        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            # In our case Django translates this string based
            # on the cookie's value (the same as "request.LANGUAGE_CODE")
            # Details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/
            msg = _('Email is already taken')
        else:
            msg = _('Activation link has been sent to your email.')

            user = User(email=email)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            user_activation__create_email_confirmation(info.context, user)

        return UserRegister(msg=msg)
```

---

**Note:** I have not tested yet these changes in production, but in production I use just one server where frontend and backend live behind `nGinx` and this is the reason why CORS settings live in `development.py` instead of `production.py`. Also in production `credentials: 'include'` possibly could be changed to `credentials: 'same-origin'` (ie more strict).